# how to make SATA drive appear as removable drive?

Tags: windows, sata, ahci, removable

Now my secondary drive shows as non-removable. (AHCI mode is set in BIOS). So, I need to make it removable.

Comment: see if the answer to [this related question](http://superuser.com/questions/117563/usb-stick-appearing-as-hard-disk-drive-not-removable-storage-device) answers your question.

Comment: @quack - the link in that answer appears to be broken now.

Comment: I've found a possible alternate link and added as comment to that answer

Comment: @quack - no, that approach is for USB drives only.

Answer (score 5):

[This program](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm), called HotSwap will enable hot swapping for SATA drives in Windows.

Comment: I am using it for my JMB363-based controllers, works flawlessly. OP has not revealed hardware details, it's still a nice suggestion though, so +1. OP: Reading linked page before using is recommended to get a grasp what it is doing. In short, it's workaround for crippled drivers. But watch out, theoretically you may have crippled hardware, i.e. not supporting hot plug capability. If your controller is not listed on the page, you should google for possible stories of other users having it before trying to hotswap via it. Checking controller's datasheet can also be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You could insert the drive in an external enclosure and connect it on Firewire, USB2 or USB3.