# Eject USB drive using the explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, eject

When I right click a drive in the *This PC* view which is associated with an SD card I have the option in the context menu to *eject* it. If it is associated with a USB flash drive this option doesn't come up. In order to eject my flash drive I have to click the icon in the tray bar for *safely removing hardware and eject media*. Why is that not possible using the explorer by right clicking the drive?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/350551/8972

Answer (score 0):

The UI of Microsoft Windows can be quite inconsistent in some aspects. Things are often not where you expect them to be, which results in poor UX.

This feature is successfully implemented in other OSes without any side effects, so I can only conclude that it is a shortcoming.

Windows development happens in secrecy ("behind closed door"). I have read that the process is quite "compartimentalized". This might be a symptom of that. Due to the closed nature of the process, we can only speculate.

It is possible to add a contextual menu:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors

I suppose one could create a script to cleanly unmount the disk and make it callable from the contextual menu using the above information.