# what is the major difference between usb flash drive and usb pen drive?

Tags: usb, bios, usb-flash-drive

I need to update my BIOS. I have downloaded the bios update tool to create the usb flash drive. using that utility tool it asks to select an usb flash drive and problem here is i have connected the usb pendrive but it is not showing in the list.

do i need to any other third party tool to use my pendrive as a flash drive?

Comment: I would say these are synonyms. The problem you experienced *may* be because this software expects "removable bit" on the device to be set, or something similar. Read [*USB stick appearing as hard disk drive, not removable storage device*](https://superuser.com/q/117563/432690) and compare it to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try another USB port, not colored.  Not all PC BIOSes can use all available USB ports ... I have a number of PCs that can only access USB1 and USB2 ports while booting and in BIOS, not USB3.

Answer (score 0):

They are synonymous.

Try connecting the USB device before launching the utility, as it may only scan for available devices as it's launching.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a very basic formatting of the USB drive, FAT32, formatted under Windows. BIOS/UEFI don't like odd partitions from Linux or Apple, and most other exotic formats.